# Retirar elementos do final de uma lista em C

Tags: c

Estou com um problemas onde minha lista esta retirando todos os elementos e deixando apenas o ultimo e penultimo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LISTA{

    int dado;
    struct LISTA *prox; 




}lista;


lista *insere(lista *p, int valor){

    lista *novo;
    novo=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->dado = valor;
    novo->prox = p;
    return novo;

}


void imprime(lista *p){
    lista *novo;
    for(p = novo; p!= NULL; p=p->prox){
        printf("%d",p->dado);

    }


}

/*lista *retira(lista *p, int valor){


    lista *aux = NULL;
    lista *novo = p;

    while(novo != NULL && novo->dado != valor){
    aux = novo;
    novo = novo->prox;  
    }
    if(novo == NULL){
        return p;
    }
    if(aux == NULL){
        novo = novo->prox;
    }else{
        aux->prox = novo->prox;
    }
    free(novo);
    return p;

}*/


lista *retiraFirst(lista *l){
    lista *tmp = l;
    tmp = l->prox;
    l->prox = tmp->prox;
    l->prox--;
    return tmp;


}


lista *retiraLast(lista *l){

    lista *ultimo = l,
    *penultimo = l;

    while(ultimo->prox != NULL){
        penultimo = ultimo;
        ultimo = ultimo->prox;

    }
    penultimo->prox = NULL;
    ultimo->prox= penultimo;
    return ultimo;



}






main(){

lista *l;
lista *primeiro, *ultimo;
    l = NULL;
    l = insere(l, 20);
    l = insere(l, 30);
    l = insere(l, 40);
    l = insere(l, 50);
    l = insere(l, 60);

    imprime(l);
    printf("----");
    //l =retira(l, 40);
    //l = retiraFirst(l);
    //imprime(l);
    printf("----");
    l = retiraLast(l);
    imprime(l);

}
```

Comment: Qual das funções está mal então? a do `retira` ?

Comment: a do retiraLast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente a função de imprimir está mal, da maneira que está fazendo está a mexer na lista original, ou seja, ao fazer `p=p->proximo` vai avançando na lista, depois perde o inicio da lista.

Deve de fazer assim:

```
void imprime(lista *p){
    lista *novo=p;
    for(; novo!= NULL; novo=novo->prox){
        printf("%d  ",novo->dado);

    }
}
```

---

Na função `retiraLast` o erro está em `l=retiraLast(l)` deveria de ser `ultimo = retiraLast(l);` na `main`, pois a função está bem implementada (tendo noção que não retirar mesmo na lista esse elemento, dando `free`).

O problema desta implementação é que nao vai conseguir dar `free` ao ultimo elemento, porque caso queira percorrer a lista e dar free ao ultimo elemento nao vai conseguir voltar ao inicio e por isso deveria de criar na struct um apontador para o inicio da lista.

Como por exemplo assim:

```
typedef struct _l_elemento
{
    /* string armazenada */
    char* str;
    /* apontadores para elementos vizinhos */
    struct _l_elemento *proximo;
    struct _l_elemento *anterior;
} l_elemento;

typedef struct
{
    l_elemento *inicio;
    l_elemento *fim;
    int tamanho;
} lista;
```

Sugiro ver um pouco da minha implementação da lista no [**GitHub**](https://github.com/fabiouds/FEUP/tree/master/PROG2/BIBLIOTECAS_PROG)

Comment: Entendi. Vlw pela ajuda darei uma olhada sim.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro criar um struct to tipo "nó", onde irá armazenar seus dados, e controlar o primeiro e o ultimo dentro da struct lista. E você deve criar somente uma lista e passá-la como referencia (via &) para suas funções para garantir que está editando a mesma lista. Veja no código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LISTA{
        struct no *pri;
        struct no *ult;
}lista;

struct no {
        int dado;
        struct no *prox;
};

void insere(lista *l, int valor);
void retira(lista *l, int valor);
void imprime(lista *l);

void imprime(lista *l){
        struct no *atual;
        atual = l->pri;
        while(atual != NULL){
                printf("%d\n", atual->dado);
                atual = atual->prox;
        }
}


void insere(lista *l, int valor){

        struct no *novo = malloc(sizeof(struct no));
        novo->dado = valor;
        novo->prox = NULL;

        /* primeiro item da lista
           pri == ult */
        if(l->pri == NULL) {
                l->pri = novo;
                l->ult = novo;
        }
        l->ult->prox = novo;
        l->ult = novo;
}

void retira(lista *l, int valor){
        struct no *atual, *achou = NULL;
        atual = l->pri;
        while(atual != NULL){
        /* se estiver no primeiro elemento */
                if(l->pri == atual &&
                        atual->prox->dado == valor){
                        achou = atual;
                        l->pri = achou->prox;
                        free(achou);
                        break;
                }else{                                                                                                                                                
                //olha uma posição na frente para não precisar voltar na lista                                                                                         
                   if(atual->prox != NULL && atual->prox->dado == valor){                                                                                                                  
                   // salva o proximo elemento                                                                                                                                         
                      achou = atual->prox;                                                                                                                                             
                   // atualiza o ponteiro do atual
                      atual->prox = achou->prox;
                    /* libera o elemento */                                                                                                                        
                      free(achou);                                                                                                                                                            
                      break;                                                                                                                                                           
                }

            }
                // avança o ponteiro
                atual = atual->prox;
        }

}


int main(){
        lista l;
        l.pri = NULL;
        l.ult = NULL;

        insere(&l, 10);
        insere(&l, 20);
        insere(&l, 30);
        insere(&l, 40);
        insere(&l, 50);
        insere(&l, 60);

        imprime(&l);
        printf("\n");

        retira(&l, 40);
        retira(&l, 50);
        imprime(&l);
}
```